# Beginner RPG map system

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, ascii, console-application

Unfortunately, I've hit a roadblock on the RPG that i'm making.

I've made a map (in a .txt file) that I want to display to the player, but I want to be able to alter the map during gameplay and use coordinates to implement collision detection and portals for example. For this to work, I need to store my map in a two-dimensional array. The issue is that i have never worked with two-dimensional arrays (I am still a beginner), so I have no idea how to use them.

My question is: How do I make my program read the .txt file one character at a time and how do I store those characters in a two-dimensional array? (the size of the array is 32 by 128)

You can find the .txt file here: [map1.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wzsHS7iz9OS-WndihFFNOMXt4h18PPwl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                data.Add(line);
            }

            //read line 5 character 6
            char c5_6 = data[4][5];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. thank you very much! However, even though i can now use coordinates, I do need to display the entire map first, how would i do that?

Comment: Use two nested for loops and use Console.Write(Write);

Comment: could you please write an example code (perhaps with some comments) because i don't quite get it (i'm very new to coding)

Comment: oh with some trying (i had to google what a nested loop was and then i tried to implement that into my code) i got it to work! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the reading one char at a time bit:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        Console.Write((char)sr.Read());
    }      
}
```

Comment: hopefully you can work out how to set the `path` and replace the Console.Write with the code that populates your 2-d array

Comment: there a nice sample here to help you with the 2-d array: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/multi-dimensional-array-in-c-sharp-with-example